# What's the most elegant way to add Redis to /etc/services?

Tags: shell, redis

So today, April 23rd 2015, the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority had decreed the use of [port 6379](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=6379) to [Redis](http://redis.io), a frabjous day indeed!

I wish to com·mem·o·rate this splendid occasion by adding the following line to my `/etc/services` file:

```
redis     6379/tcp
```

What would be the best way to go about it? By best I mean, of course, the following:

1. Needless to say, the new line should be inserted in its proper place (i.e.g. under the Assigned Numbers block, right after `gnutella-rtr    6347/udp` on my system)
2. I've considered the use of various text editors, but it feels out of place
3. Ideally, the solution should be a copy-pastable one-liner
4. I can envision the `awk` script that could do that but I'm looking for something more, a certain je ne sais quoi

*Update re @Markus' `sed` proposal:* I'm afraid the problem would be applying this "patch" on other systems that do not necessarily have the same `/etc/services` file so, expanding on point #1 above, the solution must ensure that regardless the specifics of to-be-preceding service in the file, order is kept.

*Update 2:* a few points that seem important to state - a) while not mandatory, the solution's length (or lack of rather) is certainly an important part of its elegance (similarly for external dependencies [i.e. lack of these]); b) I/we assumed that `/etc/services` is sorted, but it would be interesting to see what happens when it isn't; c) assume that you have root privileges and be careful with that `rm / -rf` command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A single line sort that puts it in the right place:

`echo -e "redis\t\t6379/tcp" | sort -k2 -n -o /etc/services -m - /etc/services`

Comment: I knew I should have gone in-house from the start ;) Seriously though - there will be no favoritism at the end of the day and only the best answers can win. Definitely the shortest answer - extra points for that. The `-m` flag gives me the hibbie-jibbies a little - what if /etc/services isn't sorted to begin with (i.e. non-standard, valid doubt against all answers BTW). In any case, I suggest you edit the answer and remove the `sudo` - no one bothered had with that anyway ;)

Comment: The `-m` is just to make sure those comment lines do not move. A non-sorted services will stay non-sorted. `sudo`? Where did you see that? :)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in the rules against answering my own question - **this one uses Redis exclusively**:

```
cat /etc/services | redis-cli -x SET services; redis-cli --raw EVAL 'local s = redis.call("GET", KEYS[1]) local b, p, name, port, proto; p = 1 repeat b, p, name, port, proto = string.find(s, "([%a%w\-]*)%s*(%d+)/(%w+)", p) if (p and tonumber(port) > tonumber(ARGV[2])) then s = string.sub(s, 1, b-1) .. ARGV[1] .. "\t\t" .. ARGV[2] .. "/" .. ARGV[3] .. "\t\t\t# " .. ARGV[4] .. "\n" .. string.sub(s, b, string.len(s)) return s end until not(p)' 1 services redis 6379 tcp "remote dictionary server" > /etc/services
```

Formatted Lua code:

```
local s = redis.call("GET", KEYS[1])
local b, p, name, port, proto

p = 1
repeat
    b, p, name, port, proto = string.find(s, "([%a%w\-]*)%s*(%d+)/(%w+)", p)
    if (p and tonumber(port) > tonumber(ARGV[2])) then
        s = string.sub(s, 1, b-1) .. ARGV[1] .. "\t\t" .. ARGV[2] 
        .. "/" .. ARGV[3] .. "\t\t\t# " .. ARGV[4] .. "\n" 
        .. string.sub(s, b, string.len(s))
        return s
    end 
until not(p)
```

***Note:*** a similar challenge (https://gist.github.com/jorinvo/2e43ffa981a97bc17259#gistcomment-1440996) had inspired this answer. I chose a pure Lua script approach instead of leveraging Sorted Sets... although I could :)

Answer (score 2):

How about a python script, Itamar?

It works on the notion of extracting the port number (called the index in the code) and if we are above 6378 but have not yet printed our Redis line, print it, then mark that sentinel true and just print all lines (including the one we are on) after.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
lines = open("/etc/services").readlines()
printed=False
for line in lines:
    if printed:
        print line.rstrip()
        continue
    datafields = line.split()
    if line[0] == "#":
        print line.rstrip()
    else:
        datafields = line.split()
        try:
            try:
                index,proto = datafields[1].split("/")
                index = int(index)
            except:
                index,proto = datafields[0].split("/")
                index = int(index)
            if index > 6378:
                if not printed:
                    print "redis           6379/tcp    #Redis DSS"
                    printed = True
            print line.rstrip()
        except:
            print datafields
            raise
```

The relevant section on my file for comparison:

```
gnutella-rtr    6347/tcp    # gnutella-rtr
#                          Serguei Osokine <osokin@paragraph.com>
#               6348-6381  Unassigned
redis           6379/tcp    #Redis DSS
metatude-mds    6382/udp    # Metatude Dialogue Server
metatude-mds    6382/tcp    # Metatude Dialogue Server
```

Notice the line above Redis is a range. Short of breaking the range this is a workable solution for me. You *could* break the range but IMO this works just fine. Splitting the range seems a bit much for a simple, elegant script. Especially considering the likelihood most services files don't have the unassigned ranges listed (this is on OS X) - and that they are in a comment anyway.

## UPDATE

If you don't care about the local file and it's comments, this gets you all currently assigned ports which are not Reserved or Discard-ed:

`curl -s http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.csv|  awk -F',' '$4!~/(Discard|Unassigned|Reserved)/ && $1 && $2+0>0 && $1!~/FIX/ {printf "%-16s\t%s/%s\t#%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4}' > /etc/services`

The FIX test is because some of those lines have embedded newlines - which can be a pain in awk.

Comment: Heh, one could implement it in Go, then running the compiled binary could be a one-liner. ;)

Comment: This one's definitely the most robust and extensible solution - the only drawback is that uses the comical scripting language that, while being current favorite coding choice, is a dependency that I'm reluctant to admin into the scope of this project. A compiled binary, be it in Go or ANSI C, while being the most peformant for sure, does not resonate well with the spirit of the, ehm, challenge.

Comment: well it is a dependency you'll find already installed on virtually every modern OS which uses /etc/services. ;) Awk isn't *quite* the same every where either - which is why I now have awk scripts for OS X (which uses "the one true awk") and different ones for Linux (and in some cases I install a different awk to handle it in Linux). :/ The simple stuff is usually the same but once you get into the more complex stuff it can break. Same actually goes for sed as well.

Answer (score 2):

An idempotent awk one-liner that inserts 6379 in order would be:

```
awk -v inserted=0 '/^[a-z]/ { if ($2 + 0 == 6379) { inserted=1 }; if (inserted == 0 && $2 + 0 > 6379) { print "redis\t\t6379/tcp"; inserted=1 }; print $0 }' /etc/services > /tmp/services && mv /tmp/services /etc/services
```

Comment: Perfect - my first choice atm :)

Answer (score 2):

Real men don't use sed/awk :)

```
TMP_SERVICES=/tmp/services.$RANDOM

while read line
do
  printf %b "$line\n" >> $TMP_SERVICES
  if [[ $line == *"6347/udp"* ]]; then
    printf %b "redis\t\t6379/tcp\n" >> $TMP_SERVICES
  fi
done<"/etc/services"

mv -fb $TMP_SERVICES /etc/services
```

Comment: Well said, but what about real fanboys? ;) My only concern - you're specifically targeting `6347/udp` which could be iffy on some system.

Comment: Idk, shouldn't /etc/services be standardized? At least to a point where 6347 is on all systems...


P.S surprised to see nobody came up with the curl -o http://my/script.sh | bash approach yet :)

Comment: It's standardized... like electrical sockets are, and anyone can edit her/his own anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '/6347\/udp/a redis     6379\/tcp' /etc/services
```

good luck!

## update

```
sed -i '/6347\/udp/a redis \t\t 6379\/tcp' /etc/services
```

looks better ...

## update 2

lol

```
sed -i ''"$(echo $(echo $(grep -n $(awk {'print$2'} /etc/services | awk -F "/" '$1<6379'{'print$1'} | tail -1) /etc/services | awk -F ':' {'print$1'}|tail -1) + 1)|bc)"'i redis \t\t 6379\/tcp' /etc/services
```

Comment: Heya @Markus - are you the same Markus that I'm thinking of? ;) That's basically what I had in mind but please see the update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I like the in-place subsitution of sed, so I combine it with an awk search of the next line in `services`

```
R="redis\t\t6379/tcp\t\t\t# data structure server" N=$(awk '{if($2+0 == 6379) exit(1);if ($2+0 > 6379) {print $0;exit(0)}}' /etc/services) && sed -i "s~$N~$R\n$N~" /etc/services
```

Comment: Enough sed! Awksome :)